# Using functions with multiple arguments with lapply in Rcpp

Tags: r, lapply, rcpp

I am trying to use Rcpp lapply function with functions with multiple arguments.

In R the same can be done with the following code.

```
lapply(y,FUN=function(x)corr(x[,2:ncol(x)],x[,1]))
```

where corr is a function that takes two arguments.

Can anybody give an example code in Rcpp for the above situation?

Comment: Do the same thing in C++, pass to lapply a function that takes one argument.

Comment: Can you be more specific. What c++ code did you try ?

Comment: This is what I have tried  `struct Compare : public std::binary_function<int,int,bool> {
  bool operator() (int a, int b) {return (a==b);}
};    

List x(List y){
 Compare c;
 return lapply(y, c (y,y))
}`

Comment: @RomainFrancois This may be a silly try But I don't know anything else to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, based on your latest comments, what you need is `mapply` rather than `sapply`, e.g. :

```
> mapply( function(a, b) a == b, 1:9, 9:1 )
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Rcpp has `mapply` (for two or 3 arguments)

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

struct Compare : public std::binary_function<int,int,bool> {   
    bool operator() (int a, int b) const {
        return (a==b);
    } 
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector test( NumericVector x, NumericVector y){
    return mapply( x, y, Compare() ) ;
}
```

which I would tend to write like this with C++11 lambdas.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector test( NumericVector x, NumericVector y){
    return mapply( x, y, [](double a, double b){ 
            return a == b ;
    } ) ;
}
```

Or even using the `std::equal_to<double>` class:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector test( NumericVector x, NumericVector y){
    return mapply( x, y, std::equal_to<double>() ) ;
}
```

However, for such trivial functions, you should be using sugar:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector test( NumericVector x, NumericVector y){
    return x == y ;
}
```